# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 187: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, azure

I have a .csv file in a blob container on azure cloud, which I am trying to read through the following line of code into a dataframe. I am getting the above mentioned error. Code :

`parts = pd.read_csv(StringIO(downloaded_blob.content_as_text()), delimiter=',', encoding= 'unicode_escape')`

Can someone shine a light on this issue.

Comment: Could you please check your cv file encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Tried various encodings did not work. Opened in VS code saw there were some special characters which I did not otherwise see. Removed them and saved the file in utf-8 encoding. It has started to work. Issue closed.